# ActiveRecord none? method fires query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this code

```
def evaluate(collection)
  if collection.none?
    []
  else
    collection.group(@group).pluck(*@columns)
  end
end
```

The `collection` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object - for e.g. `User.where(:name => 'Killer')`

Now sometimes I also pass the Rails 4 none relation `Users.none`, that's why the check for none. If I do not check for `none?`, the call to `pluck` throws an arguments exception.

The problem is whenever I query any relation for `none?` it executes the query. See here:

```
> User.where(id: 1).none?
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "v1_passengers" WHERE     "users"."id" = 1
=> false

> User.where(id: 1).none.none?
=> true
```

I do not want to execute to query just to check for none. Any workarounds?

Update: The `none?` method is actually array method thats why the query is executed. It's like calling `to_a` on the relation. What I want to know is how to figure out if the relation is a `none`

Comment: How do you expect to know if there isn't none or any record matching your query *without querying*?

Comment: My bad . .none? is actually array method. I could know none if none has been called on the relation

Comment: why do you need to do all this ? does `collection.group(@group).pluck(*@columns)` throw an error if `none` is included in collection earlier?

Comment: Yes . .pluck throws an error . ideally I would have had not check for none at all and it should just return []

Answer (score 1):

Found one method to do this without firing query. When you call `none` on a relation it appends the `ActiveRecord::NullRelation` to the `extending_values` array of the relation:

```
> User.where(id: 1).extending_values.include?(ActiveRecord::NullRelation)
=> false

> User.where(id: 1).none.extending_values.include?(ActiveRecord::NullRelation)
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can, there's no distinguishing feature between a Null Relation and an Actual Relation. Perhaps go down the rescue route:

```
begin
  collection.group(@group).pluck(*@columns)
rescue #add exact Exception to catch
  []
end
```

Not exactly clean but gets round the problem